# Failing to create Terraform aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to generate an `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter` with Terraform using the following code:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "log-group" {
        name              = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.default-lambda.function_name}"
        retention_in_days = 30
        kms_key_id        = "..."
}
    
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "invoke-lambda-cloudwatch" {
    count         =  var.log_consumer != null ? 1 : 0
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name =  var.log_consumer.name
    principal     = "logs.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log-group.arn}:*"
}  

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "lambda_subscription" {
    count           = var.log_consumer != null ? 1 : 0
    name            = "subscription-filter-${var.lambda_function_name}"
    log_group_name  = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log-group.name
    filter_pattern  = var.log_consumer.pattern
    destination_arn = var.log_consumer.arn
    depends_on      = [module.iam_role, aws_lambda_permission.invoke-lambda-cloudwatch]
}

locals {
      ...
      log_consumer = {
        pattern    = "?AUDIT ?BREADCRUMB",
        name = module.lambda-log-consumer.default-lambda-name,
        arn = module.lambda-log-consumer.default-lambda-arn
      }
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:  `Error: Error creating Cloudwatch log subscription filter: InvalidParameterException: destinationArn for vendor apigateway cannot be used without roleArn`

The thing is, the [Terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter#role_arn) says that the role_arn is optional when used with Lambda as a destination, you should skip this argument and use aws_lambda_permission.

What am I missing?

Comment: whats the data of var.log_consumer

Comment: it's an object with the following structure:

variable "log_consumer" {
  description = "Log consumer data"
  nullable = true
  type = object({
    pattern = string
    name  = string
    arn  = string
  })
  default = null
}

Comment: @VinyMachado What is the value you are assigning to `var.log_consumer.arn`?

Comment: @MarkoE it's the ARN that I'm getting from the lambda that should consume the log from the subscription filter. I'm sending this data using locals. I've updated the question with this data.

Comment: It seems that the output is actually somehow related to API Gateway.

Comment: @MarkoE for some reason, my lambda ARN was coming with apigateway on its name. Looks like this was causing the aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter to try to connect through API Gateway hence requiring the role. Not sure why the lambda ARN had this apigateway though. Something like arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path...

Comment: As I don't know what's inside of the module, I can't really say.